# Need help identifying a comic book about a wizard

Tags: story-identification

I need help with identifying the comicbook, what follows is my best effort to gather whatever I remember from reading it years ago (circa year 2000, but I'm positive it was older than that):

- The main character was a guy with white hair, who wanted to become powerful.
- Through some training and a deal of some kind he was able to become a mage of sorts. The training was set on some other world, or possibly even parts were happening in different dimension.
- His powers might have had something with travelling between dimensions, but I'm not  100% sure. Also, I seem to recall there was a hard limit of how many times he could use them.
- Then followed a part where he was famous, but someone framed him into a scandalous plot (it was a sexual scandal, I think) using his clone or a doppelganger.
- At the end of the issue

  > the main character is seen trapped in some strange state, unable to move or escape using his powers (this might have to do something with the deal he made earlier). I remember the scene at the end as this: he is suspended in mid-air, his friends look at him in disbelief while some malevolent figure explains to them that he is now trapped forever.
- His name was the title of the comic.
- The second and third parts were set on futuristic-looking planet.

Rings any bells? I'd like to read it again only I can't google it out.

Comment: You said he had powers. Could you describe them a little further? What is the setting (future, actual time, medieval, a different version of Earth...). Who trains him? With who does me make the deal?

Comment: I edited with more detail, I hope I'm not inventing things.

Comment: The Elric of Melniboné comics maybe. Wild stab in the dark.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237697/graphic-novel-white-haired-lovecraftian-occult-detective-living-in-1920s (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it, thanks to a clue I got on reddits some one asked if it was an "euro" comic, which it happened to be, dramatically narrowing the list to look through.

It was [Rork, specifically Issue #2: "Passages"](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/rork-passages/4050-32128/)

[image: Cover of *Rork: Passages*]

([Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rork))

> The character Rork is a white-haired "wizard" from another dimension who solves supernatural mysteries, before embarking on a quest to discover his origins. During his quest, he is assisted by a cast of characters including occult detective Raffington Event, astrologer Capricorn, the psychic Deliah Darkthorne (aka "Low Valley") and her daughter Sy-Ra, the immortal Yosta, and others. His enemies are the mysterious Pharass and Dahmaloch, revealed to be an analogy for the Devil himself in the later and twin Capricorne series.

Comment: ... am I the only one who read that comic book title as "Pork Passages"?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds just a bit like when Widget cast Mordred the Mystic into another dimension, but I'm not sure there are enough similarities with what you describe to suggest the character you're seeking is Mordred the Mystic.