# Graphic novel: white-haired Lovecraftian occult detective living in 1920s

Tags: story-identification, comics

A bit of a long shot, but I am looking for a comic series about an occult detective taking place sometimes before  WW II, written probably around 1990s (it is **definitely not**  Hellblazer)  The main character had characteristic snow-white hair - he looks like he is in his thirties, but apparently he is much, much older. The story that I've read was showing seemingly unconnected cases:

- A writer falls asleep and finds that he kept writing while unconscious using strange alphabet. The detective finds that underwater civilization tries to send him a warning.
- An inventor discovers a method to locate a point on any sphere that can shatter it using relatively low pressure. Someone attempts to use it on Earth.
- The detective finds a "dead zone" in the middle of a jungle - every creature that wanders inside dies and quickly turns into dust. In the cave under this area, he finds a sleeping woman (I think she was later able to kill with a touch).

Almost certainly, it is nothing from Marvel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is it Rork?

White hair, Lovecraft influences, is much older than he looks, solves supernatural mysteries.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rork

Comment: **YES!!!** Yes it is!!!

Comment: The first thing that came to mind when I read this answer was Fantasy Island.

Comment: The 2nd tome is even better but after that it meanders a bit. But there is only one artist like Andreas.

Comment: [Rork acquires his distinct haircolor when still a child, somewhere in New England, maybe in the 18th century](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8xE9.jpg)